# Root Mean Square Error of 2 raster layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

Is there a method to calculate the RMSE between 2 raster layers in QGIS?

I have 2 point cloud files, 1 edited and the other not. After triangulation of each layer I have obtained 2 raster files.

I would like to find the RMSE in terms of their vertical height diff..

Is it possible to subtract one raster from the other and form a new raster and from export and calculate the RMSE in excel based on the z value?

Comment: If you're willing to switch to GRASS GIS, then there is the module `r.regression.line` to get the full set of linear regression coordinates between two rasters. This module is available in the Processing framework.

Answer (score 5):

[WhiteBoxTools](https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools) has  [RootMeanSquareError](https://jblindsay.github.io/wbt_book/available_tools/mathand_stats_tools.html#RootMeanSquareError) tool. QGIS 3.x can access WBT through [WhiteBox for Processing](https://plugins.bruy.me/processing-whitebox.html) plugin. Definitely worth a try.

Unfortunately this RootMeanSquareError tool did not work for me when I tested it in my environment (QGIS 3.4.4 on Windows10). So let me suggest another approach, using [R](https://www.r-project.org/) through [Processing R Provider](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing_r/) plugin.

You will need to install `R` and `Processing R Provider` plugin, but its setup is really easy.

Then click on big **R** icon on top of the Processing Toolbox panel, to activate `Create New R Script`.

In the blank window, please copy and paste texts below:

```
##Raster Analysis=group
##Input_Raster= raster
##Base_Raster= raster
##Raster_Statistics= output table

delta <- (Input_Raster - Base_Raster)^2
RMSE <- sqrt(cellStats(delta, 'mean'))

Result <- data.frame(rbind(RMSE), row.names= c("RMSE"))
colnames(Result) <- c("Stats")
Raster_Statistics <- Result
```

[image]

If you click on green triangle icon (`Run Script`) you will get a new window. Assign each of your raster layer to `Input Raster` and `Base Raster` and run the tool.

[image]

It will add a new table layer `Raster statistics` with the calculated **RMSE**. Open its attribute table to see the result.

[image]